# Widget html QGIS

Tags: qgis, html, css

I am creating a mask in QGIS through the html widgwet , which, based on the value of an expression, creates or not circles. I created my css structure but I cannot integrate the question (the condition) that I generate with the expressions. Can anyone help me?

For example, I would like to generate the circle of the variable (circle_3) only if the field "125" is not null

[image: html widget]

- This is the graphic pattern of the circle in my mask (css):

```css
.circle{ width : 125px; height : 125px; border-radius : 50%; background: red; position : absolute; top : 50px; left : 150px; }

.medium_circle_1{ width : 60px; height : 60px; border-radius : 50%; background: green; position : absolute; top : 65px; left : 30px; } .small_circle_1{ width : 10px; height : 10px; border-radius : 50%; background: blue; position : absolute; top : 110px; left : 55px; } .small_circle_2{ width : 10px; height : 10px; border-radius : 50%; background: blue; position : absolute; top : 100px; left : 35px; } .small_circle_3{ width : 10px; height : 10px; border-radius : 50%; background: blue; position : absolute; top : 100px; left : 75px; }
```

- This is my JS condition:

```js
document.write(expression.evaluate(" \"125\" is not null"));
```

*NB*: If the field `"125"` in the shp is not null, then it generates the small circle (variable `small_circle_3`)

---

I am getting crazy, it all seems simple but I don't understand where I am wrong.. :

```html
<table width="" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <script>

                function expr(field, field2, class_name) {
                    return ("COALESCE(CASE WHEN " + field + " IS NOT NULL AND '" + field2 + "' ='1' END THEN '" + class_name + "' ELSE '0' END)")
                };

                function is_circle() {

                    var circle_expr = expr('"conduit_type"','"conduit_num"', '"circle"');



                    var circle = expression.evaluate(circle_expr);



                    var html_code = "<div class=" + circle + ">" + 

                    "</div>";
                    document.write(html_code);
                };

            </script>

            <style>

            .circle{
                width : 130px;
                height : 130px;
                border-radius : 50%;
                background: red;
                position : relative;
                top : 0px;
                left : 0px;
            }

            </style>

            <script>is_circle()</script>

        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML and JS code in your question please ?

Comment: I commented below

Comment: I've edited your question, you can delete your answer "comment". You can directly edit your question for add precisions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a more complex JavaScript function to create your `div` and call it when ever you want in your html document :

```
<script>
    function expr(field, class_name) {
        return "CASE WHEN \"" + field + "\" IS NOT NULL THEN '" + class_name + "' ELSE '0' END"
    };
    function is_circle() {
        var circle_expr = expr("125", "circle");
        var mc1_expr = expr("125", "medium_circle_1");
        var sc1_expr = expr("125", "small_circle_1");
        var sc2_expr = expr("125", "small_circle_2");
        var sc3_expr = expr("125", "small_circle_3");

        var circle = expression.evaluate(circle_expr);
        var mc1 = expression.evaluate(mc1_expr);
        var sc1 = expression.evaluate(sc1_expr);
        var sc2 = expression.evaluate(sc2_expr);
        var sc3 = expression.evaluate(sc3_expr);

        var html_code = "<div class=" + circle + ">" + 
        "<div class=" + mc1 + "></div>" +
        "<div class=" + sc1 + "></div>" +
        "<div class=" + sc2 + "></div>" +
        "<div class=" + sc3 + "></div>" +
        "</div>";
        document.write(html_code);
    };
</script>
<style>
.circle{
    width : 125px;
    height : 125px;
    border-radius : 50%;
    background: red;
    position : absolue;
    top : 50px;
    left : 150px;
}

.medium_circle_1{
    width : 60px;
    height : 60px;
    border-radius : 50%;
    background: green;
    position : absolute;
    top : 65px;
    left : 30px;
}

.small_circle_1{
    width : 10px;
    height : 10px;
    border-radius : 50%;
    background: blue;
    position : absolute;
    top : 110px;
    left : 55px;
}

.small_circle_2{
    width : 10px;
    height : 10px;
    border-radius : 50%;
    background: blue;
    position : absolute;
    top : 100px;
    left : 35px;
}

.small_circle_3{
    width : 10px;
    height : 10px;
    border-radius : 50%;
    background: blue;
    position : absolute;
    top : 100px;
    left : 75px;
}
</style>

<script>is_circle()</script>
```

You have just now to edit the lines like `circle_expr = expr("125", "circle");` with `expr("my_field", "my_circle_class_name");`.

---

**EDIT**

With 3 fields for display red, green and blue circles (`red_type`, `green_type`, `blue_type`), 3 other fields to count each category (`red_count`, `green_count`, `blue_count`), you can use the following HTML + Javascript code :

```html
<style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, th, td {
      border: 2px solid black;
    }

    th, td {
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .color_red{
        background-color: red;
    }

    .color_green{
        background-color: green;
    }

    .color_blue{
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .transparent{
        background-color: #00000000;
    }

    .circle{
        width : 124px;
        height : 124px;
        border-radius : 50%;
    }

    .medium_circle_1{
        width : 60px;
        height : 60px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : 62px;
        left : 32px;
    }

    .small_circle_1{
        width : 10px;
        height : 10px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : 40px;
        left : 40px;
    }

    .small_circle_2{
        width : 10px;
        height : 10px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : 39px;
        left : 57px;
    }

    .small_circle_3{
        width : 10px;
        height : 10px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : 20px;
        left : 73px;
    }

    .small_circle_4{
        width : 10px;
        height : 10px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : -5px;
        left : 40px;
    }

    .small_circle_5{
        width : 10px;
        height : 10px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : -30px;
        left : 47px;
    }

    .small_circle_6{
        width : 10px;
        height : 10px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : -40px;
        left : 65px;
    }

    .small_circle_7{
        width : 10px;
        height : 10px;
        border-radius : 50%;
        position : relative;
        top : -35px;
        left : 73px;
    }
</style>

<script>
function change_color(elem, expr){
  var color = expression.evaluate(expr);
  var newclass = document.getElementById(elem).className.replace("transparent", color)
  document.getElementById(elem).setAttribute("class", newclass);
};
function expressions_for(num){
  var n = num;
  change_color(n + ".1", "CASE WHEN \"red_type\" IS NOT NULL AND \"red_count\" >= " + n + " THEN 'color_red' ELSE 'transparent' END");
  change_color(n + ".2", "CASE WHEN \"green_type\" IS NOT NULL AND \"green_count\" >= " + n + " THEN 'color_green' ELSE 'transparent' END");
  var i;
  for (i = 3; i <= 9; i++) {
    var j = ((num - 1) * 7) + i - 2;
    change_color(n + "." + i, "CASE WHEN \"blue_type\" IS NOT NULL AND \"blue_count\" >= " + j + " THEN 'color_blue' ELSE 'transparent' END");
  };
};
function main(){
  expressions_for(1);
  expressions_for(2);
  expressions_for(3);
  expressions_for(4);
  expressions_for(5);
};
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <div id="1.1" class="circle transparent">
        <div id="1.2" class="medium_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="1.3" class="small_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="1.4" class="small_circle_2 transparent"></div>
        <div id="1.5" class="small_circle_3 transparent"></div>
        <div id="1.6" class="small_circle_4 transparent"></div>
        <div id="1.7" class="small_circle_5 transparent"></div>
        <div id="1.8" class="small_circle_6 transparent"></div>
        <div id="1.9" class="small_circle_7 transparent"></div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="2.1" class="circle transparent">
        <div id="2.2" class="medium_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="2.3" class="small_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="2.4" class="small_circle_2 transparent"></div>
        <div id="2.5" class="small_circle_3 transparent"></div>
        <div id="2.6" class="small_circle_4 transparent"></div>
        <div id="2.7" class="small_circle_5 transparent"></div>
        <div id="2.8" class="small_circle_6 transparent"></div>
        <div id="2.9" class="small_circle_7 transparent"></div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="3.1" class="circle transparent">
        <div id="3.2" class="medium_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="3.3" class="small_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="3.4" class="small_circle_2 transparent"></div>
        <div id="3.5" class="small_circle_3 transparent"></div>
        <div id="3.6" class="small_circle_4 transparent"></div>
        <div id="3.7" class="small_circle_5 transparent"></div>
        <div id="3.8" class="small_circle_6 transparent"></div>
        <div id="3.9" class="small_circle_7 transparent"></div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="4.1" class="circle transparent">
        <div id="4.2" class="medium_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="4.3" class="small_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="4.4" class="small_circle_2 transparent"></div>
        <div id="4.5" class="small_circle_3 transparent"></div>
        <div id="4.6" class="small_circle_4 transparent"></div>
        <div id="4.7" class="small_circle_5 transparent"></div>
        <div id="4.8" class="small_circle_6 transparent"></div>
        <div id="4.9" class="small_circle_7 transparent"></div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="5.1" class="circle transparent">
        <div id="5.2" class="medium_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="5.3" class="small_circle_1 transparent"></div>
        <div id="5.4" class="small_circle_2 transparent"></div>
        <div id="5.5" class="small_circle_3 transparent"></div>
        <div id="5.6" class="small_circle_4 transparent"></div>
        <div id="5.7" class="small_circle_5 transparent"></div>
        <div id="5.8" class="small_circle_6 transparent"></div>
        <div id="5.9" class="small_circle_7 transparent"></div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>main()</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! I'm not very experienced in JS. And if I want to add more conditions (circle)

Comment: @GIOVA.A88: I improved the code for all circles and create more JS for simplify the conditions coding for each circle.

Comment: Sorry for further clarification. If in my condition "case when .." I would like to add others conditions with (Coalesce) how do I do it? thank you for your availability

Comment: Code the expression in the `HtmlWidget` (click on the Epsilon) and add it in the HtmlWidget (green **+**), and look at the code inside the `expression.evaluate(...)` and adapt the code above.

Comment: The problem is: This is my function (    function expr(field, class_name) {
        return "CASE WHEN \"" + field + "\" IS NOT NULL THEN '" + class_name + "' ELSE '0' END"
    };  )        With html widget the traduction is different (document.write(expression.evaluate("coalesce(
CASE WHEN  field1  IS NOT NULL THEN layer1_name ELSE '0' END,
CASE WHEN  lfield2  IS NOT NULL THEN layer2_name ELSE '0' END
)"))  
How can I adapt it?

Comment: The function : `function expr(field1, class_name1, field2, class_name2) { return "COALESCE(CASE WHEN \"" + field1 + "\" IS NOT NULL THEN '" + class_name1 + "' ELSE '0' END, CASE WHEN \"" + field2 + "\" IS NOT NULL THEN '" + class_name2 + "' ELSE '0' END)" };` and the call : `var circle_expr = expr("125", "circle", "126", "medium_circle_1");`